# In django after deleting the posts the post images are still in the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

In django my posts are deleted but the files are not. I have a image field in the model which i want to deelete whenever the author deletes it. I'm using generics class based views delete.. so when i delete the post the posts are deleted but the image isn't deleted from the directory. i'v tried in many ways but its not working.
my models.py:

```
class postManager(models.Manager):
  def repost(self, author, parent_obj):
    if parent_obj.parent:
        og_parent = parent_obj.parent
    else:
        og_parent = parent_obj


    obj = self.model(
            parent = og_parent,
            author = author,
            content = og_parent.content,
            image = og_parent.image,
        )
    obj.save()
    return obj



class post(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_pics', null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos', null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = postManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my views.py:

```
@login_required
def post_list(request):
    count_filter = Q(likes=request.user)
    like_case = Count('likes', filter=count_filter, output_field=BooleanField())

    posts = post.objects.annotate(is_liked=like_case).all().order_by('-date_posted')


    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'posts': posts, })

class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
model = post
fields = ['content', 'image', 'video']
success_url = '/'

def test_func(self):
    post = self.get_object()
    if self.request.user == post.author:
        return True
    return False
```

my urls.py:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
```

i"m using the parent in model so, on delete(self) argument is not working.

Comment: you should override on delete() function and unlink the image related to post

Comment: It will be very nice if you tell me how to do that @Ashish

Comment: use django-cleanup. Just install it and add in installed_apps.

Comment: i have tried it too that isnot working too. @sandeep

Comment: I use django-cleanup in my all projects. it always works. When I delete image (or instance that include image) or update image, django-cleanup delete image from folder. I don't know what's wrong in your case, but always works for me.

Comment: I post the models.py file where post model has a foreignkey with self argument..that is the case..whatever i do the self argument raised an error. @sandeep

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behaviour because the **instances of `post` only store a path to the file**, like a string, not the actual file. The **actual file is stored on a filesystem**.

To delete the actual file upon deletion of an instance of `post`, you have some choices:

**1. Override the `delete` function**
e.g.

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    self.image.delete()
    super().delete()
```

**2. Add a post delete signal**
Although there is nothing inherently wrong with using signals, you should consider two points before using them:

1. A signal can be sent multiple times for a single action, so you have to handle any code that might raise errors if run more than once on a single instance (e.g. attempting to delete a non existent file)

```
try:
    os.remove(filename)
except OSError:
    pass
```

2. Because a signal is not within the *expected* flow of code, if it has a bug, it can be tricky to trace it down for less experienced developers

**3. Use a package such as [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup)**

Answer (score 2):

Use **"django-cleanup" package** to automatically remove uploaded files for **FileField**, **ImageField** and **subclasses** when they are deleted and updated. And setting **"django-cleanup"** is easy.

First, install **"django-cleanup"**:

```
pip install django-cleanup
```

Then,  set it to the bottom of **"INSTALLED_APPS"** in **"settings.py"**. That's it:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
)
```

This is [the github link for **"django-cleanup"**](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup)
This is [the pypi link for **"django-cleanup"**](https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/)

Comment: super easy, why to invent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

For me post_delete was deleting the image but the object not not deleted strangely. After using the pre_delete signal issue was solved. If anyone knows the reason for this behavior then please explain. Thank you.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Item)
def image_delete_handler(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.image and instance.image.url:
        instance.image.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 def delete(self, using=None):
    os.unlink(self.image.path)
    super(post,self).delete()
```

Comment: The self argument was the problem..because in the model their is a parent field which i use as a foreign key.@Ashish

Comment: Using self on the delete function is n't working when i overide it@NicoHaase

Answer (score 0):

You could use [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/) signal.

In your models.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

@receiver(post_delete, sender=post)
def photo_post_delete_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    photo = kwargs['instance']
    if photo.image:
        storage, path = photo.image.storage, photo.image.path
        storage.delete(path)
```

Comment: The self argument was the problem..because in the model their is a parent field which i use as a foreign key.@Renato Maretić

Comment: It's not working properly....it says a eroor raised...undefined name post@RenatoMaretić